# How to build an eBook reader that supports adobe Content Server?

Tags: sdk, ebook-reader

I'm looking into a way of building eBook reader that will support [adobe content server](http://www.adobe.com/products/contentserver/) DRM. The only solution find was Adobe Digital Editions Which is an off the shelf product and I'm looking for some sort of SDK.

any advice will help.
10x
d.
btw i don't have enough rep to post additional links
 
adobe digital editions url == www.adobe.com/products/digitaleditions/

Answer (score 3):

The [Reader Mobile SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/readermobile.html) (RMSDK), is the only way you have to build a ebook reader that works with Adobe Content Server, since it deals with the complex encryption, authentication and authorization tasks needed. 
The SDK is in C++, but can be used in most tecnologies.

Adobe Digital Editions (ADE) use it behind the scenes. But a good way to learn how to use it is to check out the code of the new version of [ADE v1.8 preview](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/digitaleditions1-8/), wich is built with .Net and WPF.

Most of the times Adobe documentation on this issues are quite poor.

If you're comfortable with this technologies, decompile it and analise its interaction with the RMSDK.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there is no AIR SDK. There is a C++ based SDK dubbed "[Reader Mobile SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/readermobile/)" and though it's misleading name it supports Desktops as well.
There SDK is not widely available and you should fill an inquiry form with adobe, if they see fit you'll get the SDK.

Comment: Daniel, did you ever make progress with this? We are looking into using it now...